# GeoServer 2.21.1 tag on github: which branch?

Tags: geoserver, github

I want to checkout the actual [GeoServer tag/version 2.21.1](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/2.21.1) from github.

Unfortunately github tells me: *this tag does not belong to any branch* and thus it can't be checked out since it does not occur in my cloned repository.

What happens here?

Answer (score 2):

Try a `git fetch -t origin` to checkout locally also the tags. Then you should be able to perform a `git checkout 2.21.1`.